# Add presence validation only on single attribute update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, rspec2

**Context:** I have a User model with an attached avatar (through paperclip). The avatar is not required when the user is created, but when the user updates his avatar on his profile I want the avatar to be required. 
When the user uploads a new avatar, only the avatar is submitted through an ajax request. At this moment I would like to return a validation error if the file_field was empty.

At first I used

```
  validates_attachment_presence :avatar, message: "The file is missing", :if => ->{ !new_record? }
```

But it doesn't work exactly as expected and it makes my validation test suite fail on `should be_valid`

```
describe User do
  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create :user
  end

  subject { @user }

  [...]

  it { should be_valid }
end
```

Which is normal.

Any idea on how I should handle this ?
The only other idea I came up with was to inject a new error in `@user.errors` from UserController#update if the file field is empty but it seems hacky.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
validates_attachment_presence :avatar, message: "The file is missing", on: :update
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#on

Comment: I don't know this syntax, I use `:on => update` instead    (@Kulbir: yes, posted 1' after David without having seen his answer, I deleted my answer)

Comment: @citraL What David has used is new ruby hash syntax. Check this [simple example](http://www.gaurishsharma.com/2012/04/new-ruby-1-9-hash-syntax.html).

Comment: The opener is using message: "The file is missing", which is new syntax, so I used new syntax also for the update option.

Comment: Nope, the problem is that if the user edits anything else like his user name, it will fail because the avatar is missing. I need the presence validation to happen only when I am submitting the avatar and only the avatar :/

Comment: Then why not using a custom validator?